# Optimizing the sub select statements to reduce the fetching time

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a query

```
select * from 
(select a.*, /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ rownum rnum 
 from (SELECT AL.AL_UID, AL.TP_ID, AL.EVENTDATE, TP.NAME, AL.EVENT, AL.FILE_NAME,
              AL.NOTES, AL.XU_NAME, AL.STATUS, AL.LOG_SOURCE, rownum
       FROM AUDITLOG AL,
            TRADINGPARTNER TP 
       WHERE  ( AL.LOG_SOURCE = 'File Deployment' )  AND TP.ID = AL.TP_ID 
       ORDER BY AL.EVENTDATE desc, AL.AL_UID desc
      ) a
 where rownum < 101
) 
where rnum > 0;
```

This is taking about a minute to fetch the results. please let me know how to optimize it in order to reduce the fetching time. Can I use joins here?

Comment: What output you actually want? Do you want all columns? If possible pls give us idea about the output you want.

Comment: Couldnt you have only one subquery rather than 2? "where rownum < 101 and rnum > 0" should do the trick no?

Comment: In fact, I don't see the need for any subqueries.  Also, an index on log_source will likely help.

Comment: @DanBracuk: The `where` clause is evaluated before the `order by`, so there has to be one level of subquery to ensure that the `order by` is applied before filtering by row number - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html .

Answer (score 1):

An index on (LOG_SOURCE, EVENTDATE desc, AL_UID desc) would be worth a look -- possibly the desc clauses are not required and try not to use them if possible.

I'd place the first_rows hint in the same query block as the predicate and order by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are often faster than `order by`.  You can try this:

```
select *
from (SELECT AL.AL_UID, AL.TP_ID, AL.EVENTDATE, TP.NAME, AL.EVENT, AL.FILE_NAME,
             AL.NOTES, AL.XU_NAME, AL.STATUS, AL.LOG_SOURCE,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AL.EVENTDATE desc, AL.AL_UID desc) as seqnum
      FROM AUDITLOG AL join
           TRADINGPARTNER TP 
           on TP.ID = AL.TP_ID
      WHERE AL.LOG_SOURCE = 'File Deployment'
     ) t
where seqnum between 1 and 100;
```

With this, you can actually write this as:

```
select al.*, TP.name
from (SELECT AL.AL_UID, AL.TP_ID, AL.EVENTDATE, AL.EVENT, AL.FILE_NAME,
             AL.NOTES, AL.XU_NAME, AL.STATUS, AL.LOG_SOURCE,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AL.EVENTDATE desc, AL.AL_UID desc) as seqnum
      FROM AUDITLOG AL
      WHERE AL.LOG_SOURCE = 'File Deployment'
     ) al join
     TradingPartner tp
     on TP.ID = AL.TP_ID 
where seqnum between 1 and 100;
```

Here is it clear that an index on `AuditLog(Eventdate, AL_UID)` will greatly improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Adding Index on EVENT_DATE column on Audit_Log table did the trick. Thanks a lot